# Buscar por data php pdo

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

Preciso fazer uma busca no banco usando a coluna **DtBase**, por exemplo: dia 26 populei a tabela com varias informações, dia 28 quero consultar o que fiz dia 26. Quero um input date ou outro método que seja mais viável para mim selecionar a data e que me retorne os registros do banco deste dia que selecionei. Se a data selecionada não existir no DtBase não mostra nada, se existir exibe todos registros da tabela do banco dentro da table html que eu tenho abaixo no código.

Coluna banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela onde quero um campo acima para selecionar a data, e que na tabela me retorne os registros do dia selecionado no campo(data):

```
<?php
$controller = new Comando($conn);
?>
    <form method="POST" action="../controller/progPrecontrole.php">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="TableCSS" >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ST</td>
                        <td>BITRUCK</td>
                        <td>Motorista</td>
                        <td>Data Saída</td>
                        <td>Origem</td>
                        <td>Destino</td>
                        <td>Previsão chegada</td>
                        <td>Carga/Manifesto</td>
                        <td>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</td>
                        <td>Agendas</td>
                        <td>Malotes</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Observação</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($controller->ListaPorTipoB() as $objProg) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php 
                            echo ($controller->RetornarCarctere($objProg->getst()));
                        ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getsaida(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarga(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getadfin(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmal(); ?></td>
                        <td class="t1" ><div><?php echo $objProg->getobs(); ?></div></td>
                        <td><a href="edita.php?id=<?php echo $objProg->getid();?>"><p>Alterar</p></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
      </form>
```

Funções que tenho até agora:

```
class ProgDAO{

private $conn;

public function __construct($connection) {
    $this->conn = $connection;
}

public function ListaPorTipoB($tipo){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DsTpVeiculo = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($tipo));
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog = new Prog();
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
                $results[] = $prog;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}

public function ListaPorTipoT($tipo){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DsTpVeiculo = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($tipo));
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog = new Prog();
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
                $results[] = $prog;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}

public function ListaPorTipoC($tipo){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DsTpVeiculo = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($tipo));
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog = new Prog();
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setcarreta($row->CdCarreta);
                $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
                $results[] = $prog;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}

public function editar(Prog $prog){
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
            'UPDATE GTCLogist SET DsStatus = :DsStatus, DsMotorista = :DsMotorista, DtSaida = :DtSaida, 
            DsOrigem = :DsOrigem, DsDestino = :DsDestino, DtPrevChegDest = :DtPrevChegDest, DsCarga = :DsCarga, 
            DsAdFin = :DsAdFin, DsAgendas = :DsAgendas, DsMalote = :DsMalote, DsObservacao = :DsObservacao,
            CdCarreta = :CdCarreta 
            WHERE ID = :ID'
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $prog->getid(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsStatus', $prog->getst(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsMotorista', $prog->getmot(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DtSaida', $prog->getsaida(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsOrigem', $prog->getorig(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsDestino', $prog->getdest(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DtPrevChegDest', $prog->getprev(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsCarga', $prog->getcarga(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsAdFin', $prog->getadfin(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsAgendas', $prog->getagen(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsMalote', $prog->getmal(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':DsObservacao', $prog->getobs(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':CdCarreta', $prog->getcarreta(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
    }
}
public function listar($id){
        $prog = new Prog();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE ID = :ID'
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setcarreta($row->CdCarreta);
                $prog->setplaca(stripslashes($row->NrPlaca));
                $prog->setmot($row->DsMotorista);
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
            }
        }
    return $prog;
}
public function ListaData(){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist');
    $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                if($row->ID == '1'){
                    $prog = new Prog();
                    $prog->setid($row->ID);
                    $prog->setdata(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtBase)));
                    $results[] = $prog;
                }
            }
        }
    return $results;
}
}
```

Control:

```
<?php

class Comando{

private $conn;

public function __construct($connec) {
    $this->conn = $connec;
}

public function ListaPorTipoB(){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> ListaPorTipoB('Bitruck');
}

public function ListaPorTipoT(){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> ListaPorTipoT('Truck');
}

public function ListaPorTipoC(){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> ListaPorTipoC('Cavalo Truck');
}

public function ListaData(){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> ListaData();
}

public function editar(Prog $objProg){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> editar($objProg);
}

public function listar($id){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> listar($id);
}

public function RetornarCarctere($x){
    $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
    return $dao -> RetornarCarctere($x);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Poste o código onde você faz as consultas no banco.

Comment: Não tenho nem uma função para busca ainda. Postei as que tenho acima.

Comment: Explique melhor o que vc deseja. Eu entendi que vc quer uma página que vc clique e abra um calendário por exemplo para escolher a data, e que essa data seja passada para consulta. É isso?

Comment: Do dia 26 de qualquer mês ou ano? não entendi.

Comment: @kevin.F você possui 3 métodos de listagem na sua DAO, qual deles você quer usar para fazer o filtro de data.

Comment: Quero um campo buscar para buscar datas anteriores, no topo da mesma page que embaixo ira puxar as informações na tabela que já existe, dependendo do dia que for selecionado. Pode ser do 26/01/2016 em diante. Essa tabela sera populada todos os dias. Por exemplo: hoje populei com varias informações, amanha quero consultar o que fiz hoje, ai dia 28 quero consultar o que fiz dia 26. Um input select, que busque as datas que desejo consultar as informações na tabela abaixo.

Comment: @Thomas Lima qualquer um, o que mais for viável.

Comment: @Kevin.F o que imaginei é o seguinte: 2 campos de data (inicial e final) para buscar todos os registros desse período, ai no método listar você passa um array com os seus parâmetros: listar(params). E no método listar você faz um foreach no seu array montando sua clausula WHERE DtBase between '2016-01-26' AND '2016-01-26'. Seria isso???

Comment: @Thomas Lima Não poderia ser um WHERE DtBase = '2016-01-26'  e só com um campo ? Não vejo problema, em fazer um between porem para ser mais especifico do modo acima ficaria melhor.

Comment: @Kevin.F certo... ficou um pouco confuso a parte em que você diz que deseja trazer os registros do dia 26 e nesse resultado os dias anteriores tbm... você quer trazer somente os registros do dia selecionado... ou os registros do dia selecionado + os dias anteriores???

Comment: @Thomas Lima, somente os do dia selecionado.

Comment: usa um pedido ajax fica mais facil ao servidor

Comment: Ainda não achei uma solução, alguma ajuda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer uma busca mais fácil eu utilizo uma maneira quando se trata de busca única. Por exemplo, fazer uma pesquisa que busque tudo que seja do dia **26/01/2016**.

Então no `SELECT` eu faço assim:

`SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATA, 103) = '26/01/2016'`

Note o uso do `CONVERT`. Eu converto a data em texto e no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` e faço um `WHERE` na data que vem do formulário `HTML`. Esse jeito estaria comparando data no formato texto.

No formulário você pode ter um campo `text`, com máscara talvez: `__/__/____`. E quando o `PHP` resgatar esse campo você pode por no seu `SELECT` no `PDO`.

Comment: Tens algum exemplo prático para se basear ?

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, não tive tempo de criar as tabelas e testar 100%. Mas aproveitando o código que você postou, segue uma solução:

Código:

```
<?php

$data = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'dt');

?>

<div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <?php
                foreach ($controller->ListaData() as $objProg) {
                    echo "<a href='/?dt=". implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/", $objProg->getdata()))) ."''>". $objProg->getdata() ."</a>";
                }
            ?>
            <a id="open-first">Código Status</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="../controller/progPrecontrole.php">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="TableCSS" >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ST</td>
                        <td>BITRUCK</td>
                        <td>Motorista</td>
                        <td>Data Saída</td>
                        <td>Origem</td>
                        <td>Destino</td>
                        <td>Previsão chegada</td>
                        <td>Carga/Manifesto</td>
                        <td>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</td>
                        <td>Agendas</td>
                        <td>Malotes</td>
                        <td colspan="2">Observação</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($controller->listar($data) as $objProg) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php 
                            echo ($controller->RetornarCarctere($objProg->getst()));
                        ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getsaida(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarga(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getadfin(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmal(); ?></td>
                        <td class="t1" ><div><?php echo $objProg->getobs(); ?></div></td>
                        <td><a href="edita.php?id=<?php echo $objProg->getid();?>"><p>Alterar</p></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
      </form>
```

método listar da DAO:

```
public function listar($data, $id = null){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE 1=1";
        if (isset($data) && !empty($data)){
            $sql .= " AND DtBase = :dt ";
        }
        if (isset($id) && !empty($id)){
            $sql .= " AND ID = :ID ";
        }

        $prog = new Prog();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if (isset($data) && !empty($data)){
            $stmt->bindValue(':dt', $data);
        }
        if (isset($id) && !empty($id)){
            $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $id);
        }
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setcarreta($row->CdCarreta);
                $prog->setplaca(stripslashes($row->NrPlaca));
                $prog->setmot($row->DsMotorista);
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setadfin($row->DsAdFin);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setmal($row->DsMalote);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
            }
        }
    return $prog;
}
```

Note que tentei alterar o mínimo possível para você aproveitar o que já está pronto. Mas te aconselho a refatorar o seu código.

Acrescentei um link nas datas que você imprime no topo da tela, para a mesma página, após eu recupero essa data e passo como parâmetro no método listar($data).

Na DAO eu alterei o método listar para filtrar pela data.

OBS: Se os atributos da classe Prog() forem iguais os do banco, você pode substituir fazer a seguinte depois de `$stmt->execute()`:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Prog');
```

Dessa forma o próprio PDO te devolve um Array de objetos. =)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35434/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-lima-buscar-por-data-php-pdo)